# Google Drive / Owncloud Alternative for Ubuntu

Tags: server, file-sharing, google

I am looking for an alternative of Google Drives that works/installs in Ubuntu server. Something similar that offers the same or most of the functions in Google Drive, like file upload, syncing, sharing files, etc..

Note that I am not looking for a client to connect to Google Drive like Grive. I am looking for a server or service that can be installed in Ubuntu Server and that it resembles the way Google Drive works with documents and user groups.

For better understanding of what I am looking for, we can see http://owncloud.org/ which has options like Calendar, events, contacts and other stuff that anybody that has used Google Drive for documents will know.

Comment: You did try UbuntuOne right? *blush* What is the functionality that Drive has that UbuntuOne has not? Not sure I understand your question.

Comment: Yes I have, obviously google drive has much more than just uploading files and sharing them. There is also shared file editing and much more.

Comment: @LuisAlvarado Is there any problem with Google Drive? Or, do you want something with more functionality than Google Drive that you can administer?

Comment: One issue I can see is not willing to keep your personal documents on a third-party provided service.

Comment: The company wants to keep everything inside the company, but with the features that google drive or own cloud offers. They have an ubuntu server, so this is why I am looking for a solution that works in Ubuntu server.

Comment: I've been using Oogwave for some time now, after dropping Skydrive because of problems.
It shares files fluently, fast storage and secure.
I recommend it for professional Office & Windows users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Owncloud runs nicely on an ubuntu server.
see installation documents here:

http://software.opensuse.org/download/package?project=isv:ownCloud:community&package=owncloud

Comment: ownCloud is fantastic if you have access to a server, quite easy to set up and you can add SSL by getting a free cert from StartSSL